# Can a troll survive without its head?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The specific situation is the troll is targeted by *psychic scream* and has his head blown up. So would he somehow regenerate a new head or would this manage to kill him or would he survive but lose all personality and memories?
I need to know!

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The question "Can a Troll survive being decapitated?" is asking if the troll's head is _removed_ not if its destroyed.

Comment: destroying the head has the same effect as removing it.